# Duplicated output with Watchdog library

Tags: python, duplicates, watchdog

I'm working with watchdog library, and want to send e-mails when a file is saved on a folder.
My problem is that when I save any pdf file on the folder, the module registers 4 modified events, and send four e-mails. Can anyone suggest how can I fix it ?

Here is my code. I used print just to exemplify.

'''

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

   

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print('Modified')


folder_to_track = 'path'

observer = Observer()
event_handler = Handler()
observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_to_track, recursive=True)
observer.start()


try:
    print('Monitoring')
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()
    print('Done')
observer.join()
```

'''

Output:
Modified
Modified
Modified
Modified

Comment: Try to inspect the `event` object that is being passed to `on_modified`. It might have attributes on it that will help understand the different events the function is triggered for. The OS might fire several different events for a single file save

Comment: Also, if the directory you monitor happens to be a git repository, you might get multiple events, one for the actual file you changed and one for a change inside the `.git` subdirectory. This can be solved by using `recursive=False` or by manually ignoring events from `.git` subdirectory (the `event` object has `_src_path` attribute`)